# Should I write a paper describing my comparisons and user guides for free tools?

Tags: computer-science, paper-submission

I have already done a project for an organization about android non-functional testing and now they've forced me to write a paper about that.

I have read many scientific papers but I've not written any yet. So I really don't know if I can publish my work as a paper.

This project was about non-functional testing tools in Android and my task was to find existing free tools (best tool for each test) and write a user manual for each of them. (I have done this for almost 8 non-functional tests)

Does this sort of comparison seem like it would be publishable in an academic journal? This work seems like it would be helpful for others, but doesn't seem like "real research."

Comment: Who is this "they" you're talking about? Could they perhaps give you some guidance beyond suggesting a journal? Try asking.

Comment: Have you written a seminar report or a BSc thesis? Write the same, but only the contribution parts (no background and expose). Then start removing text, until you land at the required page limit. This is hard and it's totally overdoing it, but a viable option is you really have absolutely no idea.

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE. Your question was about to be closed ("shopping questions" are considered off topic here), so I eliminated your last paragraph (asking your journal recommendations), and rephrased the question / title. Please feel free to "edit" my edits as appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exploratory work that you have done in non-functional testing tools can be easily summarized in a *kind of* survey paper. You need to enumerate the tools that you have played with, describe the features and limitations (even with a summary table) and describe your tool selection process (free tools seems like a criteria that you did taken into account). Further, you can even detail the *tests* that you did with the different tools.

You can then make a extended critique over the existing tools, pointing out the most valuable features and, then, pointing out the lacks, limitations and suggesting *further research directions* that need to be done in that area (e.g. suggesting the implementation of missing features or other ways of testing).

Comment: Thanks buddy. I was confused about writing a review or a survey and your answer really helped me to get an idea.